# Ruby Mysql cannot insert special character

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding

using ruby's mysql gem i'm inserting a new row into a table wich has encoding utf8_spanish_ci.

here's the code i'm executing

```
require 'mysql'
con = Mysql.new(#connecionparameters)
rs = con.query("INSERT INTO `qubi_horoscopo`.`signos` (`name`) VALUES ('acción')")
```

and when i query the table i get the following result :

> id name
>
> 1  acciÃ³n

i've checked that i'm using the same collation in the database, table and column.
so i don't know what's going wrong.

any idea? thanks!

Comment: What character encoding is your database configured with? Looks like UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as an ISO-8859 encoding to me.

Comment: the database is configured with utf8_spanish_ci

Comment: What encoding is the Ruby code using?

Comment: i've inserted #encoding: utf-8 on the beggining of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this executing

```
con.query("SET NAMES UTF8")
```

right before my insert query.

i hope this helps anyone having the same problem. i don't know if it's the best solution.